# App Engine Version 1.7.6 old_dev_appserver.py Model.key().id() not returning the correct id

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been unable to get the new `dev_appserver` to work. When I roll back to the `old_dev_appserver` my application is having trouble fetching data from the datastore because `model.key().id()` doesn't seem to be returning the correct `id`.

Anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Example:

When looking at the datastore in `_ah/admin` I can see that the entities have and `id` of `5764607523034234880` but calling `entitiy_instance.key().id()` returns `5188146770730811000`

In other words calling `Model.get_by_id(entity.key().id())` returns None. I believe it should return the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.7.6 changed the default ID allocation from sequential to scattered, which results in such big ID numbers and the problems you've encountered. There's a [bug registered](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9030&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) to fix this issue.

Meanwhile, my suggestion for local development, is to manually set ID allocation back to sequential, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore) (Specifying the Automatic ID Allocation Policy)

Answer (score 2):

I found that something changed betwene 1.7.5 and 1.7.6 that caused these `long` number to be truncated in a `json.stringify()`.

I fixed the issue by casting the `long` id to `str` before placing in the `dict` to stringify.